# Retrieving Image Path from Database and setting it to Image View

Tags: android

I'm new to android development and I hope you can help me.

I am able to save the image path by using the following code

```
   @Override
    public void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Uri targetUri = data.getData();
            picture_location = targetUri.toString();             
            studentsDbAdapter.insertImagePath(studID ,picture_location);

        }   
    }
```

and I'm trying to set the Image view from the path by using the following code:

```
public void showpic() {

    LoginDataBaseAdapter db = loginDataBaseAdapter.open();
     boolean emptytab = false;
     boolean empty = db.checkPic(null, emptytab);

    //Cursor cursor = loginDataBaseAdapter.fetchProfileImageFromDatabase();  

     if(empty==false)  
     {  


        String pathName = studentsDbAdapter.getImapath(studID);

         try {
         InputStream path = getAssets().open(pathName);
            Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(path);
            targetImage.setImageBitmap(bit);
         } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


     }

    }
```

But it doesn't show anything. I hope you can help me.

here is my checkpic code:

```
public boolean checkPic(String count, Object object) {

        boolean empty = false;
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM ImagePath", null);

        if(cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if(cursor.getInt(0)== 0)
            {
                empty = true; //rows not null;
            }
            else
            {
                empty = false; // rows null;
            }
        }
        return empty;
    }
```

Comment: Post your checkpic func

Comment: functions seems to be ok. Make sure you call showpic function after OnActivityResult.